# How to format numeric value when casting to varchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have query similar to this:

```
DECLARE @value decimal(8,0) = 1

SELECT (CAST @value AS varchar(8))
```

How can I get output formatted with leading zeros (`00000001, 00000023, 00000623` etc.)?
How can I do that?

It is simple task in .Net or Java, but I must do it inside view.

Comment: Thank you all for fast responses! I've up voted all answers, but I chose Ivan's because he fast, correct and pointed on errors in some of the other answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
DECLARE @value decimal(8,0) = 1

SELECT RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(@value AS varchar(8)), 8)
```

Comment: I'm glad to help. Drago mi je da mogu pomoći.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000000' + CAST (@value AS varchar(8)),8)
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
declare @value varchar(8)='623';
Select ltrim(right(replicate(0,8) + CAST (@value AS varchar(8)),8))
```

#### [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6756)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`REPLICATE`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx) and [**`RIGHT`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx) to do this, like so:

```
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 8) + CAST(@valueAS VARCHAR(8)), 8)
```

### [Live Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/87238/how-to-format-numeric-value-when-casting-to-varchar)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
DECLARE @value decimal(8,0) = 1
SELECT REPLICATE('0',8-len(@value))+CAST(@value AS varchar(8))
```